# Calling method in child widget from parent widget using GlobalKey

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I am using global key to call methods from child widget from parent. I found this approach as mentioned in option2 here. 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Following is not the exact code but code snippet that am using. Search method in chid is not getting called even when its called from parent.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  bool showFab = true;
  SearchState searchState = SearchState.SHOW_MENU;

  TextEditingController _searchQuery;
  bool _isSearching = false;
  String searchQuery = "Search query";

  GlobalKey<CustomersScreenState> _customerScreenState1 = GlobalKey();


  void updateSearchQuery(String newQuery) {
    setState(() {
      searchQuery = newQuery;
    });
    print("search query " + newQuery); //This is getting printed
    _customerScreenState1.currentState.search(newQuery); //Nothing happening here. not getting called
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.7,
          leading: _isSearching ? const BackButton() : null,
          title: _isSearching ? _buildSearchField() : _buildTitle(context),
          actions: _buildActions(),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt)),
              Tab(text: "CHATS"),
              Tab(
                text: "STATUS",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "CALLS",
              ),
            ],
          )),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomersScreen(key: _customerScreenState1)
        ],
      ),

}


class CustomersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomersScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CustomersScreenState createState() => CustomersScreenState();
}

class CustomersScreenState extends State<CustomersScreen> {
  Firestore fireStore;
  List<Customer> customers = [];

  bool isLoading = false; // track if products fetching
  bool hasMore = true; // flag for more products available or not
  int documentLimit = 10; // documents to be fetched per request
  DocumentSnapshot
      lastDocument; // flag for last document from where next 10 records to be fetched
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fireStore = Firestore.instance;

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20;
      if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
        getCustomers();
      }
    });
    getCustomers();
  }

  void search(Sting query){
    //This method is not getting called.
  }
}
```

Edit 1:

```
void updateSearchQuery(String newQuery) {
    setState(() {
      searchQuery = newQuery;
      print("search query " + newQuery);
      _customerScreenState1.currentState.search(newQuery); //moved inside setState still not working
    });
  }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your issue is that the method in the child Widget isn't being called even from the parent Widget?

Comment: yes, its search method of child is not called when called from when called from updateSearchQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say only with the snippet. I think `search` method is fired using your approach but probably you're not seeing any difference in your UI because you're not firing build method after `search` method runs.
Just try to call `_customerScreenState1.currentState.search(newQuery);` inside `setState` callback in `_HomeState` class.

```
void updateSearchQuery(String newQuery) {
setState(() {
  searchQuery = newQuery;
   _customerScreenState1.currentState.search(newQuery);
  });
  print("search query " + newQuery); //This is getting printed
}
```

Comment: no, thats not the case, coz i have print statement as the first line in that statement. Also i tired the approach u mentioned. See edit 1, its still not working

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my answer to a working example of what you want to do. The only difference I see between this and your code is the fact that your chid widget doesn't have a build function and I wonder if that is interfering with your state.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  GlobalKey<_ChildWidgetState> _childKey = GlobalKey<_ChildWidgetState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ChildWidget(key: _childKey),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => callChildFunction(),
              child: Text('Print'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void callChildFunction(){
    _childKey.currentState.changeChildText();
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ChildWidget({Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  String text = 'Child widget';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

  void changeChildText(){
    setState(() {
      text = 'called function';
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont think we can do it the way u described.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please expand on why you think you can't instantiate a variable with it's exact type?

Comment: I've changed my answer to a working example and a comment about the differences from your code. Please take a look.

Comment: It cannot see _ChildWidgetState